# Download excel file in Dancer - jQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, dancer

I'm wanting to download an excel file on a form submission via AJAX POST, however I don't receive a prompt to save file when using Dancers `send_file` method.

Please see below:

Route:

```
post '/:date' => sub {
        my $report_date = param('date');
        my $data = param('stuff');
        my $rep = $report->build($report_date, $data);
        return send_file("reports/$rep", content_type => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
};
```

the `build` method in that route returns the file name once it's created. The AJAX request looks like:

```
    $('#report').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            'url': $(this).attr('action'),
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': {stuff: ...},
            'success': function(res){
                console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

The above console.log doesn't return anything, however the response I get seems alright, with the contents of the Excel file, however no prompt:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="10-2014_1414869186.xlsx"
Content-Length:7161
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Date:Sat, 01 Nov 2014 19:13:06 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
```

Do I perhaps need to do something in the success response for AJAX? If so, I'm not sure what.

Would appreciate help

Comment: Do browsers not display the popup for saving on ajax request?

Comment: ^ Yup that's the case. will have to restructure my request in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won't prompt a save dialog if you send/receive file contents via AJAX, at least that's what I've found (unless you can do something in the success response in the AJAX request).

That means the only thing to do is redirect to another URL